# Excluding Exceptions in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, exception

I have a function that scrapes data from Finviz, and part of the function compiles a list of metrics. If the website address does not exist as it iterates through a list of stocks, it will still create a row in the Dataframe that includes the name of the stock, but does not include any of the metrics. I would like it so that if it cannot find the website, the row is either deleted at the end of the loop, or isn't included at all. Any insight into how I can adjust this function would be very appreciated.

```
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            #url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
            for m in df.columns:
                output = fundamental_metric(soup,m)
                df.loc[symbol,m] = output
                df = df.replace(['-'], np.NaN)
        except Exception as e:
            print (symbol, 'Not Found')
            print(e)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to store stocks for which an exception occurred and delete those lines after looping through. The deletions of lines would happen after the `for-loop` to avoid changing the dataframe while iterating over it.

```py
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    symbols_to_drop = []
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            #url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
            r = requests.get("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="+ symbol.lower(),headers=headers)
            soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
            for m in df.columns:
                output = fundamental_metric(soup,m)
                df.loc[symbol,m] = output
                df = df.replace(['-'], np.NaN)
        except Exception as e:
            symbols_to_drop.append(symbol)
            print (symbol, 'Not Found')
            print(e)
    df = df.drop(symbols_to_drop)
    return df
```